# How to generate JWT token from azure function app

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have written a azure function for email service using azure communication service.It is working fine no issues. I will be calling this function from a react website.

Now I need to call a PUT api request from that azure function. For that I need to send apiJWTToken as header along with the request. But the apiJWTToken is generated in the website when the customer logs in. But I cannot send the JWTToken as a url parameter when calling the azure function app url due to security reasons.

Is there a way to generate the apiJWTToken in the azure itself somehow? So that I can send that along with PUT request which I am calling in the azure function app.

Comment: You cannot send the JWT token to your function due to security reasons ? How ?

Comment: To call the azure function,it is like a http url(api url). I need to call a axios get method to call that function. In this url, i can send params like, https:apiurl******/?JWTToken = localstorage.get("apiJWTToken").

Comment: I am not following. How is this a security concern ?? The whole point of a JWT is to be used from client side to access an API

Answer (score 0):

- You can get a key from the `App Key`  tab in the portal which can be used for the auth in the `axios` calls

[image]

- Just add the key which you will get from portal as a `params` in `axios` and you will be able make the put calls.  Here I have made a get call.

```
var  axios = require('axios');
var  t = axios.get("https://<YouFunctionName>.azurewebsites.net/api/HttpTrigger1?"
    ,{params : {"code":"<yourKey>"}})
.then((response)=>{
    console.log(response.status);
});
```

[image]

Comment: The OP is talking about JWT for access, so I assume per-user access. After all, what is the point of having a protected endpoint and exposing the endpoint key in your client-side code in the browser, given that you could as well have an unprotected HTTP endpoint to begin with ??